# Using pow() function throws undefined reference error in C

Tags: c, math.h

Why does the following bit of code work in C:

```
int res = pow(2, 3);
printf("%d\n", res);
```

while this other doesn't?

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;

int res = pow(a, b);
printf("%d\n", res);
```

Even if I try

```
double a = 2;
double b = 3;

double res = pow(a, b);
printf("%f\n", res);
```

I get an

> undefined reference to `pow'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A complete code snippet would be helpful...

Comment: Are you including math.h or not?

Comment: I am including math.h, yes. The first code snippet works and outputs what'd be expected. The other two give the "undefined reference to 'pow'".

Comment: Are you linking math library by providing -lm switch to gcc/g++?

Comment: In your third code snippet, the double values should have a `.0` after them. So, `double a = 2.0;`, not `double a = 2;`.

Comment: @muntoo: in this situation the `.0` is redundant. You need it (or a cast), for example in `2/3` --- `2/3.0` --- `2/(double)3`.

Comment: @pmg Still, it's "good practice".

Comment: Are you `#include`ing a library like `math.h`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

When it works, it's because the calculation was done by the compiler itself (and included in the binary as if you wrote it out)

```
printf("8\n");
```

When it doesn't work, is because the `pow` function is included in the math library and the math library isn't linked with your binary by default.
To get the math library to be linked, if your compiler is gcc, use

```
gcc ... -lm ...
```

With other compilers, should be the same :)
but read the documentation

Comment: You're spot on! GCC uses MPFR. Here's some info: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html#mpfropts

Comment: MPFR! Woh! :) Totally knock me out when I was trying exactly the same thing and can't believe what I have seen.

Answer (score 19):

`undefined reference to 'pow'` sounds like a linker error. You are not linking in the math library, even if you introduce the function `pow` by including `<math.h>`.

With gcc, use the `-lm` command line parameter to link in the math lib.

Comment: If you notice, the identical answers were posted <= 1 minute apart. That might help explain why.

Answer (score 3):

Use like this

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
     printf("pow(3.2, %d) = %lf\n", i, pow(3.2, i));  
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> pow(3.2, 1) = 3.200000

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CMake (CMakeLists.txt) tool, please add this at the end of the "CMakeLists.txt" from [Esmaeill's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963971/5595995):
`target_link_libraries( <your project name> <other static/shared lib> m)`.  The other lib is optional.

For example, entire "CMakeLists.txt":

```
# ----- 1. Runtime environment
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.0)
project( test_libs )

# ----- 2. Debugging
# for debugging with gdb in Terminal
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0 -ggdb")

# ----- 3. Global variable

# ----- 4. Software library
set( includes /usr/local/include/libxml2 )
include_directories( ${includes} )

# ----- 3. Static and shared library
# Static (A file)
set( libs_static libxml2.a )
link_directories( /usr/local/lib )

# Shared (SO file)
set( libs_shared libxml2.so )
link_directories ( /usr/local/lib )

# ----- 4. File to compile

set( sources test_compiler.c )
add_executable( test_libs ${sources} )
# This is for math.h tool: "-l m" which calling "libm.so"
target_link_libraries( test_libs ${libs_static} ${libs_shared} m)
```

The "m" is same with "-l m" in command line input, which called the "libm.so" file that is the shared library generated from math.h (and math.c if there is). Here is [a web link for how to use static and shared library](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html).

Answer (score -6):

> undefined reference to `pow'

because power to any number must have an integer value as power

```
pow(x,y)
where, x must be real and y must be a whole number
```

Comment: I know this is old, but just to mention, this is not correct, pow() takes two double arguments. ;)