# Undefined Reference error for power function in C

Tags: c, gcc, pow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem using pow() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174080/problem-using-pow-in-c)
>   [Undefined reference to `pow&#39; and`floor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671366/undefined-reference-to-pow-and-floor)

I am using gcc 4.6.1.

**Code snippet:**

```
int main(void)
{

 int x= 2;
 int y = pow(3,x);
 printf("%d\n",y);

 return 0;
}
```

**Terminal:**

```
avinash@titanic:~/Desktop/DSF$ gcc power.c -o power
/tmp/ccTJ7vAH.o: In function `main':

power.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I replace x by 2 then it gets executed in an expected way. Doesn't pow function accepts variables as it's parameters?

Note: I have included stdio.h and math.h in the source file.

Comment: If you have pow(3,2) the compiler can compute that directly and doesn't have to call the function.

Comment: If you included stdio.h and math.h in the source file, then show us that in the code rather than showing us incomplete code and then telling us what's missing.

Comment: @KeithThompson- Sorry. But "include" term was appearing to be Bold without actually going for the bold type. So I dropped the #include lines, but i have mentioned that I have included both the libraries under note.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the `-lm` command-line switch to link in the math library (`-l...` means "link in the *_*_ library"; `m` is the math library):

```
gcc power.c -lm -o power
```

Comment: Or rather `gcc power.c -lm -o power`. The lib has to come after the source file.

Comment: This is not the proper order of the arguments. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc

Comment: @ruakh- No change. Got the same error message.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin- It worked! But may I know why I need to add that swith (-lm)? 2) If it's all about linking the library then why it get's executed when I replace x by any constant no.?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Both ways work for me, but O.K.: since you, Daniel, and the OP's outcome all agree, I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for the -- correction, I guess?

Comment: @AvinashSonawane: That's because GCC will "optimize away" a call to `pow(3, 2)`, replacing it with its result, so it never gets to the linker.

Comment: Why I don't have to add that switch (-ls for example) for stdio.h? Why  is it so in case of math.h? Do I have to add the switches for all the header files excluding stdio.h while linking the program?

Comment: @AvinashSonawane: GCC does link most commonly-used libraries by default; the math library is the most common library that's *not* linked by default. So you don't usually have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

The pow function is part of the math library. Therefore, the invokation of your compiler should be as follows :

```
gcc power.c -o power -lm
```

Where -lm is the switch instructing the linker to perform linking with the math library on your system.

Comment: @Daniel-It worked! But may I know why I need to add that swith (-lm)? 2) If it's all about linking the library then why it get's executed when I replace x by any constant no.? 3) Why I don't have to add this swith in case of linking other libraries like stdio.h?

Comment: `gcc` always implicitly links the source with the standard C library. Obviously, you're programming in C, so you're most probably going to use the library anyway, so adding an extra -lc to your command line every time would be weird. If you replace the 'x' by a constant, the compiler - knowing what the pow function does - turns that into a constant and avoids actually calling the function at runtime.

Comment: @Daniel- So did u mean math.h is not a part of standard C library as stdio.h?